# Executing a .m file from the Linux command line

Tags: programming

I have some code in a file named `Demo-3.m`, It can be evaluated in Mathematica 9. The final expression in the file is

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "fintempimg.jpg", fintempimg];
```

How can I execute `Demo-3.m` in Linux using the command-line? Please give me a solution with an example.

Comment: I think you can use script to do this, like `math -script file.m`. [Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaScripts.html) has very useful step by step detail.

Comment: Oh my god!! thanks for @xslittlegrass solution, it can work :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [xslittlegrass](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1364/xslittlegrass) posted in a comment to the question, the file `Demo-3.m` can be run on Linux by issuing

```
math -script Demo-3.m
```

at the command line.

More information on *Mathematica* scripting can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html) .